# Не работает динамически созданный скрипт

Tags: javascript

Почему то не хочет работать динамически созданный скрипт... Если вставить в ручную, то показываться содержимое элемента будет. Вот такой скрипт:

```
<div id="container" name="9bf31c7ff062936a96d3c8bd1f8f2ff3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="handler.js"></script>
```

Самое содержимое хандлера:

```
function init() {
    var conts=document.getElementById("container");
    var hash=conts.getAttribute("name");
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    conts.appendChild(script);
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'output/?hash='+hash;
}

init();
```

Содержимое script не показывается. Но если в ручную вставить:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="output/?hash=9bf31c7ff062936a96d3c8bd1f8f2ff3"></script>
```

То показываться будет.

Comment: Содержимое чего должно показываться?

Comment: содержимое созданного скрипта.

Comment: Посмотрел свойства, юзер агент почему устанавливает свойства:

script {
display: none;
}

И они не снимаются, даже если указать элементу скрипт display: block;

Неужели никто не сталкивался с данной проблемой? Может я что-то не то делаю...

Comment: Вы изобретаете квадратное колесо. Делайте как всем через AJAX.

Comment: Делал бы через аякс, если бы это было доступно. Но он не доступен....

Answer (score 5):

Вероятно, вы запускаете `init()`, скрипт до того как загрузится страница, соответственно найти `container` он не может, выход:

```
function init() {
    var conts = document.getElementById("container");
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    conts.appendChild(script);
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://gist.github.com/zba/4770239/raw/705211c2578c0947d3f4c6cd71f538e3a0be82b8/gistfile1.txt';  // грузим вот этот скрипт https://gist.github.com/zba/4770239#file-gistfile1-txt
    script.onload = function () {
        run(); //выполняем функцию run() из загруженного скрипта
    };
}

window.onload = init; // ждем загрузки, и только потом выполняем.
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/NqDzg/)

если у вас используется `jQuery`, то вместо `window.onload` делайте

```
$(init);
```

Comment: Да нет, находит и заполняет его необходимым тег-скриптом. Но Браузер на него вешает почему то script { display: none; }
Содержимое подгружаемого скрипта обычный текст в document.writeln()

Comment: топикстартер, если вам нужен текст для отображения, - то некошерно его подгружать как скрипт

Comment: Согласен, но пока другого решения найти не могу.

Comment: скрипт text/javascript должен запускаться а не  рисоваться

Comment: для получения отображемого текста существует [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Ага, это конечно отличный способ.. но не кросс-доменный.

Comment: а вот именно потому, что вы пытаетесь получить данные с другого домена это и не работает(for security reason). [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) вас спасет.

Comment: Воспользовался бы, если бы делал для себя. Но тут пользователи и у некоторых нет возможности установки хеадеров (как я понял, в установки для PHP нужно это проделывать).

Comment: нет, для того чтобы выставить хедер надо в php написать

    <?php
    header(header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: вашдомен");)


[описано здесь](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html)